# How to call fragment from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use the `fragment`, and i open another view in the same `fragment` it's open properly, But the problem is, I can't get that how get back to the first view.

If i call `fragment` by the object of first fragment it remove the older value which is like in the `Edittext` or other data.

Can any one Help me?

It's work like,

I call first fragment name *fragone*, and insert some value in this in `edittext`, now i want to open another view using fragment in the same named *fragsecond*, Now i want to go at *fragone*, So what can I do for that????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use Fragment on android3.0(Tab app) in that i got this as worked.

```
Fragment duedateFrag = new DuedateFrag(true);
FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_tasklistdetail_lay, duedateFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: No view found for 0x... (some constant)

Comment: @KhushalChouhan do you find solution of your problem as i am facing the same...please help out!!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I found the solution. setTargetFragment and getTargetFragment can do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setTargetFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29). An example is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.html)