# Open Fragment from another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

is it possible to open a fragment B from fragment A by tapping on a button in fragment A? Both fragments are part of a main FragmentActivity. How can I handle that?

[image: Open fragment B from fragment A]

EDIT:

The Tabs are implemened like that:

```
 ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);




    Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText("");
    Tab tab2 = actionbar.newTab().setText("");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener<AFragment>(this, "tab1",AFragment.class));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener<BFragment>(this, "tab2",BFragment.class));

    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_a);
    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_b);

    actionbar.addTab(tab1,0,true);
    actionbar.addTab(tab2,1,false);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831728/start-a-fragment-via-intent-within-a-fragment. A link that should help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105099/how-to-call-fragment-from-fragment

Comment: Yes, but the actual code will vary depending upon what those tabs are. Action bar tabs? `PagerTabStrip`? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to onClick():

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new projectInformationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = 
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```