# Open fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I´m building an Android Application and trying the default navigation that Android Studio generates from the scratch.

How should i open a new fragment inside another fragment?

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Comment: Look At this answer to go a fragment from a fragment by clicking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57753406/11675817

Answer (score 1):

Replace **Fragment B** from **Fragment A**:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_container, new fragmentB());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Done**

Comment: Thanks, going to try with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) approach. You define an Interface, Implement the Interface on an activity, store an instance of the interface that you defined (using onAttach call) and cal the methods there whenever you need them.

Fragments should be independent, and they don't know about any other fragment on your application

Comment: Thanks, gonna try and i'll let you know.