# Return to previous Fragment from a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager and inside it contains 3 fragments.

In Fragment 1, there is a button that when clicked opens a `FragmentActivity`.

Inside `FragmentActivity`, there is also a button that when clicked sends a string to the previous fragment it was invoked from and update its UI.

My question is how to return to the previous fragment to update its UI?

In `MainActivity` that holds the 3 Fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); // doesn't reload menu items

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }

    }
}
```

The PagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FirstFragment(); 
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ThirdFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

The FragmentActivity:

```
public static class TheFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TextView text;
    private Button btnToHome;

    public TheFragmentActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("something")); // should return 'shenanigans'
        btnToHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToHome);
        btnToHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // when clicked, return to FirstFragment
                // updates FirstFragment UI with a String from this Activity
            }
        });

    }
}
```

FirstFragment that invokes `TheFragmentActivity`:

```
public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btnNew;

    public FirstFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeholder, container, false);
        btnNew = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
        btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TheFragmentActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("something", "shenanigans");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105099/how-to-call-fragment-from-fragment) & try this

```
Fragment duedateFrag = new DuedateFrag(true);
FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_tasklistdetail_lay, duedateFrag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It won't load the ViewPager as the Fragment contains in the MainActivity. Plus, I don't have any view to replace the id to (`R.id.main_tasklistdetail_lay`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using overriding `onActivityResult` to the Fragment I wanted it to be updated.

In `FragmentActivity` onClick, I set result to be captured in the Fragment I wanted previously:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("fromLoggedIn", "some string");
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

In the `FirstFragment` I overrided

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(PlaceholderFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "data= "+data.getStringExtra("fromLoggedIn")); // returns "some string"
        }
    }
```